# How to get the current operating system in MSBuild?

Tags: linux, bash, msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a .NET Core 1.1 console project created with Visual Studio 2017.
After building the project, I need to run a powershell script so I added the following to the `MyProject.csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="PostcompileScript" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="execute-tasks.ps1" />
</Target>
```

Now I need to build the project in a Linux environment, I need to instruct MSBuild to run `execute-tasks.sh` instead of `execute-tasks.ps1` when it is running in Linux.

I believe this is achievable via the `Condition` attribute, but **is there an MSBuild variable that holds the operating system name?**

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The variable is `$(OS)`, usually checked against being or not being `Windows_NT`:

```
<Exec Command="./foo.sh" Condition=" '$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT' " />
```

Comment: Where is the official docs for the OS directive? What other OS options are there?

Comment: There is an issue discussion about the values that can be returned in the official MSBuild repository here – https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/539 – I have not researched what the final outcome was, but apparently the possible values are Windows_NT, Unix and perhaps OSX (the matter of the issue in Github).

Comment: It's documented here by msbuild author @rainersigwald https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/2468#issuecomment-324694593

Answer (score 36):

Using `$(OS)`, as documented in other answers, can distinguish between `Windows_NT` and `Unix` (which includes both Linux and macOS), but not between different Unix-like systems.  If you are using MSBuild 15.3 or later (which is very likely), you may want to consider using [`[MSBuild]::IsOsPlatform()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions#msbuild-property-functions):

```xml
<Exec Command="./foo.sh" Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('Linux'))" />
```

The argument can be the name of any [`OsPlatform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.osplatform) member.

Comment: Nice, that worked for me (using `Windows` instead of `Linux`).

Comment: There's even `$([MSBuild]::IsOSUnixLike())` as a shortcut to the above 

Comment: This doesn't work in a docker container

Answer (score 0):

You can use the target something like this. Seems OS version is not an environment variable in MSBUILD.

```
 <Target Name="AfterBuild">
          <Exec Command="foo.exe arg1 arg2" Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' " />
 </Target>
```

or another example, this may be cumbersome.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="OSVersion" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OsVersion>$(registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion@CurrentVersion).$(registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion@CurrentBuildNumber)</OsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="OSVersion">
    <Message Text="Version: $(OsVersion)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Just that registry access isn't that helpful on *nix systems. even if run on windows, it only works when using the full framework msbuild, not the .net core version that ships with the CLI.

Comment: Ok I wasnt aware of the of .net core version.